# Accessing Element From ngRepeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

How can I access a given record inside an `ngRepeat` loop from the controller, ultimately for form validate?

I have the following form which can have records dynamically added/removed by the user:

```
<table class="table table-condensed span12" id="tableParticipants">
  <!-- snip -->
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="person in people">
      <td><input type="text" pattern="[0-9]*" data-provide="typeahead" placeholder="8675309" ng-model="person.empid"></td>
      <td><input type="text" data-provide="typeahead"  placeholder="Firstname Lastname" ng-model="person.name"></td>
      <td><input type="text" placeholder="Title" ng-model="person.title"></td>
      <td style="text-align: center"><i class="icon-remove" ng-click="removeParticipant()"></i></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

On submitting the form I need to make sure that the employee IDs are valid, else I will get a database error.  So, when I work through the loop:

```
$scope.people.forEach(function(element, index, array)
{
  if ($element['empid'] == BAD)
  {
    // set corredponding ngRepeat row to error
  }
}
```

How can I access that given row for the particular record?

Comment: Why do you need to do that?  You can populate your people array with an error message and then just have the UI show that if it exists...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do something like the following.  Add a css class name to the array item and/or an error message.  The rest should be handled by Angular which will update.  You have options of show/hiding a message, adding a class, etc.

```
<tr ng-repeat="person in people" ng-class="person.error">
 <td><input type="text" pattern="[0-9]*" data-provide="typeahead" placeholder="8675309" ng-model="person.empid"></td>
  <td><input type="text" data-provide="typeahead"  placeholder="Firstname Lastname" ng-model="person.name"></td>
  <td><input type="text" placeholder="Title" ng-model="person.title"></td>
  <td style="text-align: center"><i class="icon-remove" ng-click="removeParticipant()"></i> <span>{{person.errorMessage}}</td>
</tr>

if ($element['empid'] == BAD)
{
  $element['errorMessage'] = 'Invalid Id';  // could bind or show a span/depends.
  $element['error'] = 'error';  // set to whatever class you want to use.
}
```

Comment: Bingo.  That is what I was asking about, in a roundabout way it would seem.  I knew I shouldn't directly access the DOM elements to maintain the spirit of AngularJS, just didn't express it well enough.  I have rows popping up red now.  Thank you!

Comment: Transitioning from a jQuery way of doing things can be tricky at first.. Glad it worked.